# What Portal 2 functionality is unavailable when the PSN is down?

Tags: portal-2, psn

What Portal 2 functionality is unavailable when the PSN is down?  Can Portal 2 owners still play the single player game?

Comment: [Online?  More like *yawn* line. Why play with boring weirdo losers when you could play with yourself? I mean...](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/4/25/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Online play against other PS3, PC, or Mac users is unavailable.  Single-player and split-screen co-op play are still available.

Comment: Does the PS3 have anything like the Xbox 360's achievements, which sometimes require online connectivity to either get or record?

Comment: PS3 does have "Trophies" - I think they're supposed to work when offline.

Comment: Yes you can get them offline and they will sync with Sony server next time you're online. Just don't crash your PS3 HDD while Sony PSN is down... :)

Comment: I think I heard that if you didn't load Portal 2 to your PC before PSN went down, then you can't do it now until it's back up.